# Using limit parameter in fiware-orion does not have any effect

Tags: fiware-orion

We try to get bikerenting data from public instance of fiware-orion. We followed the description in the API doc

No matter how we supply "limit" and "offset" params, we don't get more than ten entries.

To reproduce, you need a Fiware account. With your credentials you can request a token

> curl -s -d "{\"username\": \"USERNAME\", \"password\":\"PASSWORD\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://orion.lab.fiware.org/token

Once you have the token, you can query orion

> curl "http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/queryContext?limit=200&offset=0&details=off" -s -S -H"X-Auth-Token:TOKEN" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d ' {"entities":[{"type":"bikerenting","isPattern":true,"id":"Tusbic.*"}]}'

This gives us the entities with the following ids

> ```
>     "id" : "Tusbic.2",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.3",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.4",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.5",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.6",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.7",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.8",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.9",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.10",
>     "id" : "Tusbic.11",
> ```

When we change the id in the query to some other value, for example to "Tusbic.12", we get the data for that entity. Which proves that there are more entities than just ten.

Does anyone knows how to get proper pagination?

Answer (score 0):

As far as we have checked "Tusbic.*" entities are not managed locally by Orion instance at orion.lab.fiware.org, but by a Context Provider registrated in that instance. Up to now, Orion was running with a CPr forwarding capping of 10 (`-cprForwardLimit 10`) for performance reasons.

Limit has been raised to 50 and it seems that now the query works ok (up to 16 entities are returned):

```
curl 'http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/queryContext?limit=200&offset=0&details=off' -s -S -H"X-Auth-Token:TOKEN" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d ' {"entities":[{"type":"bikerenting","isPattern":"true","id":"Tusbic.*"}]}'  | grep Tusbic
        "id" : "Tusbic.2",
        "id" : "Tusbic.3",
        "id" : "Tusbic.4",
        "id" : "Tusbic.5",
        "id" : "Tusbic.6",
        "id" : "Tusbic.7",
        "id" : "Tusbic.8",
        "id" : "Tusbic.9",
        "id" : "Tusbic.10",
        "id" : "Tusbic.11",
        "id" : "Tusbic.12",
        "id" : "Tusbic.13",
        "id" : "Tusbic.14",
        "id" : "Tusbic.15",
        "id" : "Tusbic.16",
        "id" : "Tusbic.17",
```

Comment: Thanks @fgalan for increasing the forward limit. That helped us already with Tusbic. Unfortunately there is bikerenting data from another provider, called "Villo" and they have more than 350 stations. Therefor, back to my original question: Is the answer that we cannot paginate via limit and offset when entities are not managed locally by Orion but by a ContextProvider registrated in that instance and the CPr forwarding capping is set to a value which is lower than the number of entities?

Comment: Raising the cap so much could have perfomance issues in Orion running orion.lab.fiware.org (which is a public and shared instance). Thus, I'd recommend you to set you own Orion private instance, so you can configure it without CPr forwarding capping. However, we acknowledge that it is unefficient to have N request for entities that all them have been registered in the same CPr, so we will work in a future Orion version to improve this (an issue has been created about this at github.com: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1044). Thanks for the feedback!